# Firebase not-in and != operators error does anyone know why?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using "firebase": "^7.9.0" installed via npm install firebase - according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#example_data) I should be able to access the "not-in" and "!=" operators but they're not available and throw an error: FirebaseError: Invalid value "not-in" provided to function Query.where() for its second argument. Acceptable values: <, <=, ==, >=, >, array-contains, in, array-contains-any]

Has anyone else come up against this? Am I working on an old version of firebase??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [change log](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7210_-_september_17_2020) this feature was added in version 7.21.0

Comment: Thanks - it appears I had an old install via expo that was saved in node modules. Cheers

Comment: Alright, please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue :)

Comment: yep done there's a timer on accepting was waiting for that to run down :)